# Version Control for Virtual Appliances

Tags: version-control, backup, virtualization, virtual-machine

My understanding of a virtual appliance is 1+ pre-configured VM(s) designed to work with one another and each with a pre-configured:

- Virtual hardware configuration (disks, RAM, CPUs, etc.)
- Guest OS
- Installed & configured software stack

Is this (essentially) the gist of what an appliance is? If not please correct me and clarify!

Assuming that my understanding is correct, it begins to beg the question: what are the best ways to back up an appliance? Obviously a SCM like SVN would not be appropriate because an appliance isn't source code - its an enormous binary file representing an entire machine or even set of machines.

**So how does SO keep "backups" of appliances? How does SO imitate version control for appliance configurations?**

I'm using VBox so I'll use that in the next example, but this is really a generic virtualization question.

If I develop/configure an appliance and label it as the "`1.0`" version, and deploy that appliance to a production server running the VBox hypervisor, then I'll use software terms and call that a "release". What happens if I find a configuration issue with the guest OS of that appliance and need to release a `1.0.1` patch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this may be the sort of issue that Chef and Puppet are trying to solve... but its a systems admin question (hence votes to move) rather than a dev one.

Comment: Good point Murph - yes I agree to move it to a more suitable location. Is this something I can do, or can request to do?

Comment: Hopefully the votes to close (move in this case) should get to 5 shortly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen and used, appliances are released with the ability to restore their default VM, probably from a ghost partition of some kind (I'm thinking about Comrex radio STL units I've worked with). Patches can be applied to the appliance, with the latest patch usually containing all the previous patches (if needed).

A new VM means a new appliance - Comrex ACCESS 2.0 or whatever, and 1.0 patches don't work on it. It's never backed up, rather it can just be restored to a factory state. The Comrex units store connection settings, static IP configuration, all that junk, but resetting kills all that and has to be re-entered (which I've had to do before).